# Is it possible to replace an attribute within a URL of image src using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change some values in a src url using jQuery?

Example:

```
<img src="imgd.php?src=disco-ballin-corrected--05.jpg&quality=10&w=500&h=500&cf" style="width:100%;" class="image-optimised">
```

I have an ajax call that updates some other page data for me but need to adjust quality value from my slider

```
$('#slider').slider().on('slideStop', function(ev){
    var newVal = $('#slider').data('slider').getValue();
    if(originalVal != newVal) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "imgd.php?src=disco-ballin-corrected--05.jpg&quality="+newVal+"&json",
            dataType: "json"
        }).success(function(data){
            $('.image-details-quality').html(newVal);
            var sizeInMB = (JSON.stringify(data['size']) / (1024*1024)).toFixed(2);
            var sizeInKB = (JSON.stringify(data['size']) / 1024).toFixed(2);
            $('.image-details-size').html(sizeInMB + 'mb' + ' / ' + sizeInKB + 'kb');
            $('.image-details-dims').html(data['width'] + 'px' + ' x ' + data['height'] + 'px');
            $('.image-details-type').html(data['mimeType']);
            $('.image-optimised');
        });
    }
});
```

The class image-optimised is what I want to use and it's to update the value on the HTML page not within this ajax call.

Comment: Sorry i meant to change the src url parameters

Comment: try $(element).attr('src').match(regular_expr) and change them and set them back $(element).attr('src', newVal);

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#slider').slider().on('slideStop', function(ev){
    var newVal = $('#slider').data('slider').getValue();
    if(originalVal != newVal) {
         document.querySelector(".image-optimised").src="imgd.php?src=disco-ballin-corrected--05.jpg&quality="+newVal+"&w=500&h=500&cf";
           originalVal=newVal;
    }
});
```

Simply change the src, which will trigger reload?

Comment: I will be changing the URL as well but i think i can do it around a different value by pulling the image name in thats been selected. ill work it out but thanks